# Cannot generate webservice client using axis2, eclipse and tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, apache-axis, webservice-client

Hi I am new in using axis2. I would be glad if someone helps me on this..

axis2 version: 1.8
eclipse version: eclipse-jee-2021-12-R
apache tomcat version: 8.5.73

I have WSDL and I would like to generate webservice client using axis2 with Eclipse however it returns the following message:

Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : null
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenConfiguration.(java.util.Map)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3508)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2244)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.command.Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.execute(Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.java:157)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:421)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:361)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:256)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:296)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:436)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:266)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:93)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(WizardPageManager.java:264)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(DynamicWizard.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:832)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:472)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:263)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:283)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:319)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:253)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:389)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)

Comment: Same error here, any solutions so far?

Comment: Can you provide the WSDL so I can't try it by myself?